# Quantidade de elementos em JSON

Tags: php, json

Como posso descobrir a quantidade de elementos de um arquivo json atráves do PHP.

Veja o exemplo do meu arquivo:

```
[{"descricao":"Fotografia","codigo":784},{"descricao":"Filmagem","codigo":789}]
```

Gostaria de verificar a quantidade de elementos, que nesse caso deveria ser 2, ja tentei realizar um json_decode antes para tentar manipular o json, mas sempre me retorna um NULL. E com o sizeof me retorna apenas o valor 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça o [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) na string json e use [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) no resultado:

```
$parseJson = json_decode('[{"descricao":"Fotografia","codigo":784},{"descricao":"Filmagem","codigo":789}]');
echo count($parseJson); // 2
```

Comment: era o que vinha tentando, mas só funciona se eu usar um utf8_encode($str_json) antes do json_decode(). Vlw

Comment: Conseguiu @tkmattos? Acabei de testar mesmo com esse json e está tudo bem

Comment: Se você está tendo que usar `utf8_enconde()`, então porque não abrir o arquivo com o bloco de notas e verificar se está salvo como ANSI. Se estiver altere para UTF-8 e remova as funções do PHP.

Comment: Deu certo @Miguel, perfeito

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida o json vem de um webservice

Comment: De nada @tkmattos